# Server application unavailable in a MVC2 application over IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-6

I created an application pool, and i assigned to it a test application(simple 1 view that renders hello, one action and one controller ) that i made in MVC

The thing is that when i executes as many times as i want it works, but after some hours (i dont know why), if i enter again into my server and i execute it, crashes.

The thing is that the only user that executes this application is me. Im wondering the following:

- Are in IIS 6 any default setting that says something like: "Pool, shutdown if there arent request during certain amount of time"?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

In the application pool there wasn't only one application, there were two.

The first one, configured to run on asp.net 2.0, and the other (my test application configured to run on Asp.net 4.0). Every time I reset the pool and execute one application, the other crashes.

> The solution: All the applications running on the same application pool should be configured to run in the same version of asp.net